# Java open sources list

Tags: java, open-source, jakarta-ee

Any idea what are the possible palces to find the list of available open sources/commercial softwares at a sigle place for java platform? , Yes i'm not expecting maven repositories , I just want to know if anyone maintaining the list available in a single place

Thanks in advance,
- Srinivas

Comment: There is no single "best" answer (if any) to this question, please make it CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea what is the best palce to find the list of available open sources/commercial softwares at a sigle place for java platform?

There is no such "the" list. The best you can get is more less up-to-date subset of something that is in a permanent evolution. Some examples:

- http://java-source.net/
- http://www.manageability.org/blog/opensource/
- http://www.java-opensource.com/
- http://oreilly.com/pub/q/java_os_directory

Answer (score 0):

Some places to get you started:

- [Java.net](http://www.java.net/projects/)
- [Project Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects_tags/java)
- [Github](http://github.com/search)

Answer (score 0):

java2s also lists quite a lot of them and also groups them by categories 
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/CatalogJava.htm